# How to support multiple versions of an Android app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, software-distribution

I have a need to have multiple versions of the same Android application running in production. Different customers use different version, based on their profile. For business reasons (which I cannot disclose), it is mandatory not to include any changes in for example user group X's application while the application must be developed in general though for different user groups. The application version used by group X should only be updated to fix critical bugs. The user groups are not based into geographical location or device, but are divided into groups by business needs (can be thought as different customers).

I'm aware that that multiple instances of the same app can be uploaded to Google Play, given that the package and name of the app is changed. But how do Google Play policies react to this?

I'm also aware that the application could be distributed from another source, via HTTP for example. Then the users must enable installing apps from untrusted sources. We also have an iOS application and as far as I know this is not doable on iOS.

What is the best practice to distribute multiple versions of the same application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Play doesn't support this, you need to either release multiple apps (where user chooses the correct app to download) or implement this behavior inside your app ("Hmm... this is the lowest group, so use this old class instead of this new one")

EDIT: Theoretically, you could use closed beta and alpha channels for this, so that all users get the base version, people you add to testers list for beta will get beta version and testers for alpha will get alpha - that means you could do up to three groups. But managing it would be a hell